# "gcc -o test test.c; test" does not produce any output

Tags: c

I've written a very simple program that is meant to covert a char to its equivalent ASCII value (eg. A = 65), but I'm getting no output at all. where am i going wrong?

Program: test.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char test = 'c';
  int key = (int)(test);
  printf("%d",key);
  return 0;
}
```

Bash script to compile and run

```
gcc -o test test.c
test > output
```

I always end up with output being an empty file.

Comment: Don't worry you are only the 1,000,000th Unix programmer to have been caught by this! Test is a builtin unix command that just returns true

Comment: What language are you using? `int(test)` **is not C**. If you're using C++, tag this question C++ and remove the C tag. Otherwise, fix your code.

Comment: Wouldnt feel so bad about it. Apart from anything else its a superb example of how to post a question. Relevent title, appropriate tags clear and concise statement of your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**test** is also a command line application:

> test - check file types and compare values

The proper way of executing your little app would be:

**./test > output**

Comment: I was going to note, this is dependent on if it's being ran from linux right? The code would work as he typed it in a windows environment right?

Comment: @onaclov2000 His question is how to run the code on Linux environment and redirect it's output to a file. And yes, I believe the code is compilable under Win.

Comment: `test` is also a shell built-in. `/usr/bin/test` exists for when you want to programmatically launch a test, but not launch a whole shell.